# Knockout Options Binding for JSON returned from service

Tags: json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Apologies if this has already been mentioned or answered but I have looked for a few days and cannot work this out.  I am new to both Knockout and StackOverflow so bear with me please.

I am working with CakePHP and have some JSON returned from my controller which is in the following format

```
{"countries":[{"Country":{"id":"1","country":"England"}},{"Country":{"id":"2","country":"Wales\/Cymru"}},{"Country":{"id":"3","country":"Scotland"}},{"Country":{"id":"4","country":"Republic of Ireland"}},{"Country":{"id":"5","country":"Northern Ireland"}}]};
```

I am hoping to have the above counties appear as an item in a select statement with the value being set to 1 and the text displayed as the country.  However I cannot seem to get knockout to do this for me.  I am sure this is a simple question to those familiar with knockout but I cannot understand what to do all I see is the list of objects but do not know how to access the object properties on the data-bind

HTML

```
<select data-bind="options:countries, optionsText:'Country'"></select>​
```

Javascript

```
    var viewModel = {};

    var data = {"countries":[{"Country":{"id":"1","country":"England"}},{"Country":{"id":"2","country":"Wales\/Cymru"}},{"Country":{"id":"3","country":"Scotland"}},{"Country":{"id":"4","country":"Republic of Ireland"}},{"Country":{"id":"5","country":"Northern Ireland"}}]};

    var jsData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(jsData);
```

I have created a simple JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jbrr5/14/ to show what is happening any help would be appreciated with this small challenge

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data has an odd structure.  It's like this:

```
- countries
  - Country
    - id
    - country
```

The actual `id` and `country` is another level deep in the array of `countries`.  You'd have to do some hacking around just to get those to appear in the select element as-is.  It would be better if you just mapped to the inner `Country` objects.

```
var mappingOptions = {
    'countries': {
        'create': function (options) {
            // map to the inner `Country`
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data.Country);
        }
    }
};

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/jbrr5/17/)

Comment: Thanks you Jeff, the Json is generated using CakePHP serialize method which is why I believe it is so complicated.  However your solution works for me so I will continue to use this.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have very complex structure of array. For your case you have to write `'Country.country'` in `options` binding but it doesn't work because binding cannot parse such complex expression. Instead of using `options` and `optionsText` bindings you can use `foreach`:

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/jbrr5/18/

But I would recommend you change structure of your data to

`{"countries":[{"id":"1","country":"England"}]};`

or map data accordingly. In this case you could use `options` binding:

```
<select data-bind="options:countries, optionsText:'country', optionsValue:'id'"></select>​
```

Comment: Thanks Artem, this solution was also useful as well.  Thank you for answering. :)